# tests not working in IE unless nativeEvents disabled

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

When running selenium tests in IE, the tests do not click on elements that they should click on consistently when I disable native events desired capability. But it seems like that capability should be enabled. Two questions

- Is it good practice to enable nativeEvents when running selenium tests?
- If so, how do I get that to work in IE? Right now I'm using selenium server standalone jar 2.53.1 with IE driver associated with that version. I think I might have to install more packages to get clicks to work correctly in IE

Answer (score 2):

Native events are preferred over synthetic events as mentioned [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4403) because they use OS level mechanism to send keyboard and mouse inputs.
By default native events are switched on in IE driver. But they introduces some clicks and hoverOver issues.
You can read [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html) about the principles on which IE driver is built and the issues it introduced.

There is workaround to the hover issue by using `"enablePersistentHover" capability`

and there is a workaround for improving clicks by using `"requireWindowFocus" capability`

Both of them are very well described [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html)

Comment: I tried setting nativeEvents -> true, enablePersistentHover -> false, requireWindowFocus -> true, but that did not help.

Comment: @Jasmine  I think you'll have to include your code , errors and describe your clicks more for someone to understand. This way you'll have more chances to get an answer from someone.

Comment: @Jasmine have you tried `requireWindowFocus -> true` and `nativeEvents -> false` . it may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use desired capabilities as shown below and this works.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
cap.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
cap.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.merge(cap);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```